How to get custom middleware to run before AuthenticationMiddleware?
I'm sending an id_token in my cookies to a FastAPI application that also has a mounted Starlette app. I have a CustomMiddleware class that I'd like to run before the AuthenticationMiddleware for token validation. However, the AuthenticationMiddleware always runs first:
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.authentication import (
    AuthCredentials,
    AuthenticationBackend,
    BaseUser,
)
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.authentication import AuthenticationMiddleware
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse
from starlette.routing import Route


class AuthenticatedUser(BaseUser):
    def __init__(self, display_name: str) -> None:
        self._display_name = display_name

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self) -> bool:
        return True


class AuthBackend(AuthenticationBackend):
    async def authenticate(self, conn):
        print("Authenticate method fired")
        return AuthCredentials(["authenticated"]), AuthenticatedUser(
            display_name="Test User"
        )


class CustomHeaderMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        response = await call_next(request)
        print("custom middleware fired")
        return response


middleware = [
    Middleware(CustomHeaderMiddleware),
    Middleware(AuthenticationMiddleware, backend=AuthBackend()),
]


async def starlette_homepage(request):
    return JSONResponse({"message": "Hello from Starlette!"})


starlette_app = Starlette(
    debug=True,
    routes=[
        Route("/", starlette_homepage),
    ],
)

app = FastAPI(middleware=middleware)


@app.get("/")
async def fastapi_homepage():
    return {"message": "Hello from FastAPI!"}


app.mount("/starlette", starlette_app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

Running this and going to localhost:8000/ or localhost:8000/starlette I see:
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51118 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
Authenticate method fired
custom middleware fired
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51129 - "GET /starlette HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
Authenticate method fired
custom middleware fired
INFO:     127.0.0.1:51129 - "GET /starlette/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK

How can I ensure that the CustomMiddlewareruns  first so I can perform token validation before running the AuthenticationMiddleware and creating the AuthenticatedUser?

Just change their order in the list of middlewares

Sorry, I have tried that. Regardless of the order registered the AuthenticationMiddleware runs first.

The order matters. The reason why you don't see the difference is that you print the message after calling await call_next(request). So, it happens only after executing the endpoint handler

In CustomHeaderMiddleware you print the message after calling await call_next(request).
Change it to print before await call_next(request) and everything will work:
class CustomHeaderMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        print("custom middleware fired")
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response

If you need to change the order of middlewares, just change their order in the list of middlewares
